# load more button / scrolling for array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array ($users) that is sorted and now I want to make a load more button/scrolling so the browser doesnt chrashs if to much is loading.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$statement->execute();
$users = $statement->fetchAll();

foreach ($users as $row) { 
$row['username'];
}
```

It should show 5 items and if you press the load more button or if you scroll to the end of the page it loads the next 5 items. How can I do that?

Comment: You need to implement paging and use `SELECT Top 5 * FROM users`

Comment: this is called pagination, if you want to implement it on your own then you need put `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your query with values that comes from the client in some way(GET query paramaters,url parts, etc)

Comment: If you don't want to implement it on your own then have a look at PagerFanta https://github.com/whiteoctober/Pagerfanta , or if you already use a framework see if it supports pagination out-of-the-box